# Número "aleatório" sendo gerado junto com hash do md5

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em laravel e em determinado momento eu preciso gerar um valor em MD5 para atribuir a um campo no banco de dados.

O problema, é que ao gerar esse hash de MD5, está surgindo um "número aleatório" e está entrando na variável, ao invés de entrar na variável o hash criado. Veja:

```
 if($this->emptyField === 0)
 {
   
     //Criando um id do lote
     $fileId = md5(time() . rand(0, 9999) . time());
     print_r($fileId);
 }
```

Veja o que é gerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se repararem ali, são gerados 4 números (9634) junto com o hash MD5. Quando entra no banco de dados, só entra esses 4 números na coluna.

As vezes acontece de só gerar o hash MD5 mesmo.

O campo no banco é do tipo varchar(100). E o banco é MySQL.

Poderiam me ajudar ?

Segue o link do código completo, caso queiram consultar.

https://paste.laravel.io/2d6d0c04-82db-476b-b1e6-b37b5f792e68

Comment: Como a conversa se estendeu foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116917/discussion-on-question-by-gato-de-schrodinger-numero-aleatorio-sendo-gerado-ju) e pode prosseguir por lá, quem tiver interesse em ler e/ou participar, pode clicar no link. Sobre o fechamento, como o que foi apresentado se trata de comportamento esperado, nada a ser feito no escopo do site. Nestes casos, precisa fornecer um [mcve] de um problema real, e que não dependa de links externos. Na ausência destas possibilidades, a pergunta não deve ser feita neste site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prezado,
O hash gerado pelo md5 contêm 32 caracteres,
sua saída no pewview está correta, não há nada de errado.
para conferir, verifique o rand em uma variável separada, depois junte-a com os time() em uma string separada, imprima ambas antes de gerar o md5, gere o md5 e então gere novamente com as saídas anteriores em um site que forneça md5 para fins de conferência, e verás que está tudo correto. Dessa forma:

```
//Criando um id do lote
       $father = rand(0, 9999);
       print_r($father);
       echo "<br>";
       $pre_print = (time() . $father . time());
       print_r($pre_print);
       echo "<bR>";
       $fileId = md5($pre_print);
       print_r($fileId);
```

Podes contar os caracteres em: https://www.quantasletras.com/
E gerar o md5 em: [https://www.md5hashgenerator.com/](https://www.quantasletras.com/)

Comment: Segui a dica do hkotsubo e parei pra analisar o código  usando  a premissa desse seu código ai. Realmente aqueles números fazem parte do hash. Eu dei mole mesmo. Obrigado!

Comment: "Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação. Mesmo dentro do escopo do site, sua solução dificilmente seria útil a outros usuários no futuro." Esse é o argumento que deram pra fechar a pergunta. Beleza. Mas dois usuário conseguiram reproduzir o código que postei e tiveram resultados (não importando se positivos ou negativos). E outra coisa, o que garante que uma pessoa não pode estar passando pelo mesmo problema que eu ? Na verdade essa pergunta foi boa, pois, em todo o site, não tem uma outra demonstrando um problema similar (o que é difícil de acontecer).

Comment: ... Uma pessoa, que estiver passando por um problema como o meu pode olhar a resposta do Hkotsubo e essa resposta aqui, e talvez ter a solução para a sua possível dúvida. A pergunta foi "positivada" duas vezes e marcada como "favorita" por uma pessoa. Quer dizer que pra alguém ela pode ter sido útil.